# Bash if conditional doesn't work

Tags: bash, if-statement

Why doesn't this code work?

```
#!/bin/bash
    if [ "$(ls | grep a | wc -l)" -gt 2 ]
        then
        echo "asdasda"
        fi
```

Should I put the double quotes?

The new error is:

```
line 5: syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'"
```

Comment: Change `2]` to `2 ]`. The brackets need to be delineated by spaces.

Comment: I actually did that, wrote it wrong here. It still doesn't work.

Comment: This is a very poorly formed question. You don't ask "why doesn't this code work?". A better question is, "I tried this, but I get error xyz, and I narrowed it down to line nnn. Why does that line fail with that error?" Or "I expected results ... but got ... instead". When I tried the code, with the space, on a test case, it seemed to work fine. So there's something else going on that you haven't described. There's just not enough information here to help.

Comment: You are right. I put the error.

Comment: So your error says "line 6" but you are showing 4 lines of code. You are going to have to show more, especially where line 6 is.

Comment: You have a typo. The last `if` should be `fi`. That's the issue, unless you already corrected that, too.

Comment: Is this part of a larger script? Which line is line 2?? The 4 lines you are currently showing are fine.

Comment: Make sure that what you typed into the question is what's in your script.

Comment: If you edit the question to fix the errors, the question doesn't make sense any longer.

Comment: The point is it still doesn't work as it is. If it worked I wouldn't have fixed it and wrote it.

Comment: but i just copied and pasted your code into a file and then executed that file in bash and it worked. Do you have more than 3 files in the directory you are executing this in with the letter a in the file name?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't matter since I get the error I posted. I'll try to figure it out on my own. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Check your script for special characters: `cat -A script.sh`

Comment: Finally it worked. I rewrote the code several times, but it still didn't work. At the end I deleted it, created a new one and it worked. Don't ask me why cause I don't know.

Comment: @Christian, one likely explanation is that your original had DOS newlines (CRLFs) in some places, rather than being a UNIX text file (LFs only). If you had one on the `then`, for instance, it would then be parsed as `then$'\r'` -- and if you have a `fi` without a valid `then` preceding it, it's unexpected, hence the error. (Alternately, if you had a space after the `fi` but not the `then`, and DOS newlines throughout the file, that would be also consistent).

Comment: btw, using `ls` this way in scripts is very bad form. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for background on why `ls` should not have its output applied programatically.

Comment: And before you post here with syntax errors, try http://shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `2]` to `2 ]`
- `if` to `fi` at End of if

Working code:

```
if [ "$(ls | grep a | wc -l)" -gt 2 ]
    then
    echo "asdasda"
fi
```

The string `fi` designates the end of an if statement.

Reference: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/if_clause

EDIT: OP has edited his post a number of times to correct the broken code.

To answer OP's other question, yes, your use of double quotes is correct as it prevents unwanted expansion or execution, but does not prevent functionality.